Previous company messed up my Background Check. How will I handle this with new companies?
I was working in a startup (Company 1). I was always beloved by mostly everyone. My Team lead held me in high regard, my manager used to praise me all the time, the CEO was very happy. I was given somewhat special status, like leaving early, work from home, etc. , because all my members were sure that I would get the job done.
Due to low pay, and more opportunities, I chose to leave the organization. I submitted my resignation as I got another offer. I left on good terms. The experience letter, relieving letter and all were shared to me via unofficial channels (not email), (because the company had provided hard copies of the same). I sent an email to the manager, asking for confirmation that these are indeed the documents that were shared with me. But, I didn't get any acceptance. The thing is, I didn't get the Relieving letter and Experience certificate over mail. I requested multiple times, yet the manager didn't budge. I went ahead and shared the documents that I had received over unofficial channels, and sent those mails to my manager and CEO, and asked my then manager to confirm that these documents are genuine. There was no reply.
I started working in Company 2, a Multi National Company. Company 2 has strict background checks too. And my Background Verification was cleared twice: once while joining, and once while joining a BFSI Project. While transferring Employee Provident Fund (Retirement fund), I came to know that Company 1 had not cleared some Provident Fund amount. So, I sent several notices, and launched several grievances in EPF portal against Company 1, but nothing were answered. I finally decided to hire a lawyer to force EPF to take action against Company 1. And finally, Company 1 budged.
In between, I got offer from another Company 3, another MNC. I submitted my resignation in Company 2. Just a few days after my Last Working Day at Company 2, HR of Company 3 called me and stated that my Background Verification had failed because I lied. To my surprise, the Background Verification vendor got mail from Company 1 (startup) that I didn't resign. Rather I was fired for poor performance. Also, the document that I shared, was not genuine, but forged.
I felt like the Earth just slipped under me. Because, exactly 1 month before submitting my resignation, I got an award from the company for my performance (medal + cash price) in Company 1. And, my Background Verification was cleared by Company 2. I swore to HR that I didn't lie, and that I can provide a few proof about it. I also stated that I can provide an affidavit stating that I did not forge documents, and that the same documents were shared with Company 2 as well.
I tried to have a face-to-face conversation with Company 1, but they didn't even call me in. Moreover, the same documents that were sent to me via email, by Company 1, are also being marked as fake, during Background Verification. This is strictly against the IT laws set by our country. Seems like a lawsuit is the only option.
My questions are :-

Since, I do not have any offer, how will I update my profile on
LinkedIn or other job portals?

How will I explain my current situation, in case, I get calls from other companies?



Is there any chance/way to repair relations with company 1 CEO? That could be the easiest way to undo this. While the answer given is correct in theory, that doesn't come without consequences.


Seems like a lawsuit is the only option.

Hire a lawyer to work for you on this case.


Since, I do not have any offer, how will I update my profile on LinkedIn or other job portals

Maybe, list the last day that you actually worked for that company.


How will I explain my current situation, in case, I get calls from other companies ?

Tell them the truth.
